# Stern-Gerlach: Why is it probability 1/2 for cooked up silver atoms?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-spin

Why does cooking up silver atoms in an oven give them equal probability spin up and spin down?

Answer (score 1):

If you prepare many silver atoms in the exact same state each time you might get 1000 out of 1000 to come out spin up.

Or if you prepare many silver atoms in the exact same state (but different than the one above) each time you might get 0 out of 1000 to come out spin up.

And when I say might it depends on if you pick the right state to prepare them and how well a job you do of preparing the state you wanted.

When you heat up your silver atoms you are basically letting a random process interact with your system. So the random process ends up preparing your state for you and so you sometimes get the state that gives spin up 100% of the time but just as often you get the state that gives you spin up 0% of the time. Sometimes your random process ends up giving you a state that gives spin up 90% of the time but just as often you get a state that gives you spin up 10% of the time.

I'm the end you get spin up around 50% of the time. The amount you have to heat it up can depend on the magnetic field, a stronger field might mean it is much harder to interact with the spins thermally.

There is also an issue of terminology. People that like to do statistical physics might want to call the act of letting random processes set up your system be part of the preparation so they might call that mixture of sometimes this preparation and sometimes that preparation to be a thing in and of itself and call that a state.

Even if you do that, the result is a mixed state which is different than the pure state you get if you didn't let random processes setup your system.

Comment: So you would perhaps say that silver atoms in the furnace are constantly acting upon each other magnetically (if ever so weakly) and thus the spin of the silver atoms are going through a random continuous unitary transformation that on average produces equal probability spins? Or how would you describe this random process?

Comment: @user73236 They don't have to act on each other, they could absorb thermal photons while exposed to magnetic fields pointing in randomly determined directions. You could even put just silver atoms into a furnace by itself and pull it put and measure the spin then put it back in. Its just that the furnace will have to be hotter the bigger the applied external magnetic field(s) ... if any.

Answer (score -1):

It is assumed and proven that before measurement there is no distinct spin up or spin down state unless of course it is somehow prepared. General state of a particle is described as a linear combination of spin up and spin down state. If you measure the z projection you get 50 % upz and 50 % downz. If you then take upz particles and measure the x projection you get 50% upx and 50% downx. Take now, again, the 50% downx, which were chosen from upz bunch and measure z projection again, you will again measure 50 % up and 50% downz.
Now, it is obvious that system is not just described as linear superposition of spin up and spin down states, it actually is in this neither up nor down state. So, even without heating up, just by measurement of one direction(x) you automaticly prepare the state that is fifty-fifty in the other direction(z). So atoms that come out of the owen are maybe in a upz or downz state already because of some random magnetic interaction or in any other state. But being in some other state makes them in such a state that is again fifty fifty to be up or downz.

Comment: It is neither obvious nor true that a spin downx is not a linear combination of spin upz and spin downz. It is a linear combination in every sense of the word. And you can verify it experimentally by getting extreme interference from a beam that is a linear superposition of spin upz and spin down. But the whole point of cooking them is so that you get spin up with 50% and spin down for 50% for any possible direction. No preparation of a single particle pure state gets you that, you need either a multiparticle entangled state or a single particle mixed state (or a combination).

Comment: You should read more carefully my friend. I simply emphasized what you just said. Let me copy-paste here:
Now, it is obvious that system is not just DESCRIBED as linear superposition of spin up and spin down states, it actually IS in this neither up nor down state.(meaning in both at the same time)
Now if you downvoted me because you missinterpreted this sentence...heh. If you are not the one to do that then fine. But again, read more carefully.

Comment: My question wasn't about measuring a pure state created after an initial measurement.